# Multiple entries to MySQL when using PHP/JS 'add another' field

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

I need to add multiple entries to a database. Here's my form. What is the best way to save this into a mysql table so that if someone adds/enters 5 different 'appliance' entries, etc., it saves them under the same ID? Should I just add the possible POST variables/values like POST_appliance0, POST_appliance1, etc or is there a more efficient way?

http://jsfiddle.net/Commandrea/pFt4A/

```
<div id="elecNeeds" style="margin-bottom:20px"> 
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" id="addRow">Click to Add Another Item</a><br /><br /></div>
<input style="width:130px" type="text" name="appliance" placeholder="Type of Equipment">
<input type="text" name="voltage" placeholder="Voltage">
<input type="text" name="watts" placeholder="Watts">
<input type="text" name="amps" placeholder="Amps">
 <input type="text" name="phase" placeholder="Phase">
 <input style="width:165px" type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Notes">
 <br /><br />
 </div> 



var i = 1;

$("#addRow").click(function() {
$("#elecNeeds").append('<input style="width:130px" type="text" name="appliance' + i + '"      placeholder="Type of Equipment" /> <input type="text" name="voltage' + i + '" placeholder="Voltage" /> <input type="text" name="watts' + i + '" placeholder="Watts" /> <input type="text" name="amps' + i + '" placeholder="Amps" /> <input type="text" name="phase' + i + '" placeholder="Phase" /> <input style="width:165px" type="text" name="notes' + i + '" placeholder="Notes" /> <br/><br />');

i++;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your jsfiddle page to load (my network, not your page). From what I understand reading your post, you should take the different options on your page and [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) them to store in your DB in a single field. This allows you to have another field in that row with a single 'id'. Whenever you need to use the data again, you query the 'id' and do a json_decode().

Comment: Hi there- I added the code so you could see it...I am pretty much ignorant of json- and I'll like to be able to total the voltage, amps, etc. so I wouldn't mind having them in separate fields. I am guessing that since the JS will add an incremental ID to the name, it would be easiest for me to just add those values to my process.php page and the table. I'm in the middle of setting that up to see what kind of results I get.